# Send Email and Name In Email Template

Tags: html, django

I want to send my visitors' names, e-mails, topics and messages to my e-mail address via the website I prepared with Django.

## mysite/views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['my@mail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponse('Thanks for your email')
return render(request,'giris/contact.html',{'form': form})
```

> {% block content %}
>      {% load widget_tweaks %}
>
> ### Contact Us
>
> {% csrf_token %}
>          {{ form.as_p }}
>          
>      
>      {% endblock %}
>
> I want to display and e-mail the template I prepared with django-widget-tweaks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your template is for a contact form (which is displayed by your view). What exactly is not working? The way the form is displayed? Or the email itself? Is the email not sent? Do you get an error?

Comment: I can't display properly the contact.html page I've created using widget-tweaks. That's why I can't e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

```
            get_cust = RegularCustomerMaster.objects.get(id=instance)
            Message = New_Customer.Message.replace('{customer_email}', get_cust.Email)
```

now {customer_email} is your key if you pass in email actual email will send

Comment: Why doesn't the widget-tweaks work in 'mysite / contact.html'?

Comment: I am little bit confused, can you  please explain

Comment: I want to use widgets-tweaks, but I can't display the page properly. If I can view it successfully, I would like my web site visitors to send e-mail to my e-mail address.

Comment: can you explain how you solved your problem, please

Comment: Now, Send_mail (name, From_email, subject, message, recipient_list) when I use the "name ' recipient_list ' is not defined " I get this error, can you help?

Comment: sure, no problem, wait i will send you my code -> https://codeshare.io/aY0o6b see this link for my code